# JavaScript toggle button problem with reverting back to original CSS variable values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a toggle switch that changes my color variables I have set. The following code works but I want it to revert back to the original colors if clicked again. Also, if there is a better way to accomplish that Id like to learn how, this seemed to be the most direct way but I am still learning vanilla JS.

CSS:

```
:root {
  --bg-color:  #040d14;
  --text-color:  #f0f4f6;
  --border-color: #30363a;
  --highlight-color: #00c805; 
  --secondary-bg-color:#1e2124;
}
```

JS:

```
change.onclick = () => {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--bg-color', '#f7f7f7');
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--text-color', '#333');
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--border-color', '#040d14');
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--secondary-bg-color', '#ebecec');
 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So to me this looks like you are toggling between a dark/light mode. There are a ton of tutorials out there on this but this is the basics of it.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button')

button.addEventListener('click', toggleTheme)

function toggleTheme() {

    if (document.body.getAttribute('data-theme') === 'light') {
        document.body.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark')
    } else {
        document.body.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light')
    }
}
```

```css
    :root {
      --bg-color:  #040d14;
      --text-color:  #f0f4f6;
      --border-color: #30363a;
      --highlight-color: #00c805; 
      --secondary-bg-color:#1e2124;
    }

    [data-theme="light"] {
        --bg-color:  #f7f7f7;
        --text-color:  #333;
        --border-color: #040d14;
        --highlight-color: #ebecec; 
        --secondary-bg-color:#1e2124;
    }
    
    
   .container {
       background-color: var(--bg-color);
       height: 200px;
       color: var(--text-color);
       border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
   }
```

```html
<div class="container">
   Stuff
</div>

<button>Toggle</button>
```

Comment: IMHO, className dark/light would play it better with `classList.toggle()` than with get/set Attibute.

Answer (score -1):

I think your way is the best way. To remove, you can use [`.removeProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/removeProperty).

```js
document.documentElement.style.removeProperty("--bg-color")
```

**Edit**

Example of how to toggle between two states. You could also set the initial CSS custom property using JavaScript, which can be useful if you have multiple options that are not predefined.

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

```css
:root {
    --bg: red;
}
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: var(--bg);
}
```

```js
let theme = "red"
const container = document.querySelector(".container")
container.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (theme === "red") {
        theme = "blue"
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--bg", "blue")
        return
    }

    theme = "red"
    document.documentElement.style.removeProperty("--bg")
})
```

Comment: but how do i add that to the second click? and wont that remove the property completely? I want it to go back to its original state on the second click.

Comment: @robothead I added a simple of example. First you just set the property like in your question, which overrides the initial property, and then you remove the set property using `.removeProperty()` method. I think this is a nice and simple vanila JS solution.